# Overwrite all local files that are not committed

Tags: git, git-commit

I made some changes to a project and commits them.

I did `git pull` to update my local branch before pushing.

The git bash shows:

```
The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
<list of files>
```

The command `git pull -f` had the same effect. I dont what to do `git reset --hard origin/<branch_name>` because, to my knowledge that will "delete" my commits.

How do I overwrite all local files *that are not committed* and *keep the commits* to then be able to push them?

Comment: The files are not just *uncommitted*, they're untracked. As in, unknown to git. If you want to get rid of these files, look at `git clean` but be careful and use `--dry-run` first

Comment: Do you want to save the uncommitted work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reset them branch to your **current `HEAD`**. That way you'll remove any local changes that aren't committed, but won't lose any commits:

```
$ git reset HEAD --hard
```